# rational function of non vanishing Hölder continuous functions

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, holder-spaces

Conside Hölder continuous functions $f_1,…,f_m:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ (with Hölder coefficient $\alpha$). The claum is now that any rational function of $f_1,…,f_m$ with non vanishing denominator is also Hölder continuous (with coefficient $\alpha$). The author says this is trivial, but I do not see why this should be trivial!? (I could not even prove the easiest case $f(x)/g(x)$)

Do you have an idea by which it is easily proven?

Best regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such as stated, the result is not true. Take for instance $f_1(x)=e^{-x^2}$, $f_2(x)=e^{-2x^2}$, which are Lipschitz. Then $f_1(x)/f_2(x)=e^{x^2}$, which is not (globally) Lipschitz. Two conditions that will make the result true:

1. The $f_i$ are bounded
2. The denominator is bounded away from $0$

Comment: Thank you very much! This is the reason why I could not prove it! If both conditions, 1. and 2., are satisfied then the proof seems indeed trivial. Do you know less strong conditions such that the statement remains true?

Comment: I do not think you do without them.

Answer (score 0):

I it is not true in general. For example $f_1(x)= exp( \sqrt{x})$ and $f_2(x)= 5 \,exp( \sqrt{x})$. The ratio is 5, so the Holder exponent is not conserved.